# Remove Lines with Ruby

Tags: ruby, parsing

How can I use ruby to open a text file, and remove lines containing a "key phrase".

I don't want only the key phrase to be removed, I need the full line which contains the phrase to be deleted.

Comment: In the file or in what you read in?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Something like this:

```
File.open(output_file, "w") do |ofile|
  File.foreach(input_file) do |iline|
    ofile.puts(iline) unless iline =~ Key_phrase
  end
end
```

Comment: I replace the light blue word 'File', with the name of the text file I want to open?

Comment: Nope, that's what `output_file` and `input_file` are for. If you update your question a bit, I'll update the answer accordingly.

Comment: You missed a `)` on the first line before `do`.

Comment: Updated, thanks. That's what you get for typing code directly into the browser... ;-)

Comment: Getting this error, where out_file is my file name: undefined local variable or method 'output_file' for main:Object <NameError>

Comment: `output_file` is a variable that contains the file name of the file you want to write to. If you stored that in `out_file` as you mentioned it obviously won't work. Either change the code or the name of your variable. It seems like you are rather new to Ruby, the docs are rather good.

Comment: Thanks, that should have been obvious. I appreciate all the help almost working. Just 1 more error: type mismatch: String given (TypeError)

Comment: @PhilipK: You need to replace `Key_phrase` by a regular expression like `/keyword/` here. You should read a bit about basic Ruby types. Alternatively, you can just check if a string is in the line: `unless iline.include?("phrase")`

Comment: As it is now, the question is about "Remove Lines". This is not removing lines, it creates another file. In fact if output_file == input_file then it fails badly.

Comment: @inger It does, but using Ruby to move `output_file` back to `input_file` if everything worked is left as an exercise for OP.

Answer (score 1):

Is this a one-off, standalone task? Edit the file in place?
If so the following one-liner might be handy:

```
ruby -i.bak -ne 'print unless /key phrase/' file-to-hack.txt
```

This changes the file, and backs up the original.
If you want this as part of bigger program, add the loops around it for each line..

Comment: Or without Ruby: `sed -i.bak -ne '/key phrase/d' file_name.txt`.

Comment: sure, if we open up the questions's scope. BTW, s/ruby/perl/ on the above for yet another answer :)

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use inplace editing inside ruby (not from the command line):

```
#!/usr/bin/ruby

def inplace_edit(file, bak, &block)
    old_argv = Array.new(ARGV)
    old_stdout = $stdout
    ARGV.replace [file]
    ARGF.inplace_mode = bak
    ARGF.lines do |line|
        yield line
    end
    ARGV.replace old_argv
    $stdout = old_stdout
end

inplace_edit 'test.txt', '.bak' do |line|
    print line unless line.match(/something/)
    print line.gsub(/search1/,"replace1")
end
```

If you don't want to create a backup then change '.bak' to ''.